# как вывести массив в цикле

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть функция, которая получает массив:

```
$(function() {
    $("#load").click(function(){ // Выполняем если по кнопке кликнули

        $.ajax({
            url: "", // Обработчик
            type: "GET", // Отправляем методом GET
            data: {"num": num},
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                if(response == 0){ // Смотрим ответ от сервера и выполняем соответствующее действие
                    alert('Записей нет!');
                }else{
                    $("#comments").append(response);
                    num = num + 1;
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Содержимое массива, полученное функцией var_dump:

> array(1) { [1]=> array(5) { ["Email"]=> string(11) "admin@admin" ["DateComment"]=> string(10) "2016-05-04" ["TimeComment"]=> string(8) "01:41:28" ["Text"]=> string(64) "Привет, я комментарий!рпорпоплполд" ["Mark"]=> string(1) "5" } }

**Вопрос**: как мне вывести содержимое этого массива в цикле на страницу?

Вместо содержимого массива пишется слово `Array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, вам следует указать правильный Content-type. Пример php-файла:

```
$array = [
    [
        'Email'       => 'admin@admin',
        'DateComment' => '2016-05-04',
        'TimeComment' => '01:41:28',
        'Text'        => 'Привет, я комментарий!рпорпоплполд',
        'Mark'        => '5'
    ]
];

header('Content-type: application/json');  // <---- вот эта строка
echo json_encode($array);
```

Во-вторых, при ajax-запросе, также укажите тип запрашиваемых данных:

```
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'get.php',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',   // <---- вот здесь
            success: function(response) {
                $.each(response, function(i, el) {
                    var model = '<div>Email: ' + el.Email + '</div>' +
                        '<div>DateComment: ' + el.DateComment + '</div>' +
                        '<div>TimeComment:' + el.TimeComment + '</div>' +
                        '<div>Text: ' + el.Text + '</div>' +
                        '<div>Mark: ' + el.Mark + '</div>';

                    $('#models_auto').append(model);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: как мне вывести эти значения в отдельные `div`? у меня выводится просто строка со значениями.

Comment: @Денис объединить 2 ответа очень сложно

Comment: @Денис обновил ответ

Comment: @AndreiKatalkin спасибо! единственный адекватный ответ за 2 дня.

Answer (score 2):

Тебе нужно распарсить ответ от сервера с помощью $.parseJSON и соответственно передавать с сервера должен в фомате JSON. Вот пример здесь выводится селект.

```
function onAjaxSuccess(data)
{
    $('#models_auto').html('');
    var jsonObj = $.parseJSON(data);
    var html = '';
    jsonObj.forEach(function(el){
        html += '<option value='+el.id+'>'+el.name+'</option>';
    });

    $('#models_auto').append(html);     

}
```

Comment: `jsonObj.forEach is not a function` ошибка, как бороться?

Comment: а у Вас массив возвращает запрос?

Comment: да: `{"1":{"Email":"admin@admin","DateComment":"2016-05-04","TimeComment":"01:41:28","Text":"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442, \u044f \u043a\u043e\u043c\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0430\u0440\u0438\u0439!\u0440\u043f\u043e\u0440\u043f\u043e\u043f\u043b\u043f\u043e\u043b\u0434","Mark":"5"}}`

Comment: @Денис `jsonObj` что выводит?

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев ` var jsonObj = JSON.parse(response);
                                alert(jsonObj);` выводит: `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев а если вот так: `var jsonObj=JSON.stringify(response); alert(jsonObj);` то выводит массив со значениями.

Comment: @Денис ничего не понял, в `response` у вас строка или массив уже? Если массив, то никаких преобразований делать не нужно. А если строка то надо `JSON.parse(str)` делать. Сейчас вы сами не понимаете что вам приходит, и как этим управлять. Либо вам приходит не массив, а объект. А у объекта нет `.forEach`

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев в `response` у меня массив, а в `jsonObj` у меня объект или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: @Денис `response` это то что вам вернул сервер, я уж точно не могу знать что это (По стандарту он возвращает **строку** json). Тогда нужно из строки сделать массив/объект, в зависимости от того что пришло. `JSON.parse` как раз таки создает из строки массив или объект. И дальше вы можете его использовать.